# The Existence of "Simple" Prime Generating Functions

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

Obviously, we do not know an explicit and easily manipulable formula for finding every prime - that is, a function $f(n)$ which yields the $n^{th}$ prime. I've seen plenty of formulas that "cheat" in some way (e.g. encode trial division in a sum and floor functions) or only yield a very sparse set of primes (e.g. [Mills' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills'_constant)).

I'm curious about results of the existence or non-existence of $f$ satisfying certain "sanity" conditions. What is clear to me is that:

- There is no suitable rational function, because they are all in $O(x^k)$ for integer $k$, which is the wrong asymptotic.
- There is an analytic function giving primes, because [*any* sequence can be given by an analytic function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2944/which-sequences-can-be-extended-to-analytic-functions-e-g-ackermanns-funct).

However, these are really trivial observations, and they leave a very wide gap of functions for which we don't know much. Could there be any $f$ writable in terms of integrals of rational functions? Could there be an $f$ with some power series which converges quickly? Could there be some $f$ defined by an (algebraic) differential equation? I'd be interested in any (non-trivial*) result of existence or non-existence of such functions - or even about functions which always yields primes, but don't yield every prime.

(*i.e. "trivial" being a result that would hold for any sequence in $O(n\log(n))$)